# Implementation of OpenMP and Pthread

Tags: pthreads, openmp

I have written a sequential code for a simulation process. Basically the flow goes like the following:

```c
int count=0;
int i, j;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
label:
        if(j==i) continue;

        // Some vector calculations and finding out X value example: (X=i+j)
    }

    // Some calculations with respect to i value example: (K=i*0.8+0.2)
    // Example:Z=X+K;

    if(Z==0.5)
    { 
        count++;

        if(count<3)
        {
            goto label;
        }   
    }
}
```

I am new to parallel programming. How can I implement the above code using OpenMP and Pthreads.
I tried using `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)` before the first for loop and I am stuck in figuring out the next steps to be followed.

Comment: The point of using OpenMP would be to *avoid* using pthreads (explicitly).  Your compiler might implement its OpenMP support in terms of pthreads, or it might not.  You don't need to care.

Comment: We cannot evaluate code that you do not present, but supposing that you have prepared valid OpenMP-using code, the next steps are to compile and run it, more or less like any other program.  Your compiler may require you to provide a compilation option to enable OpenMP, but that's compiler-specific.  If you happen to be using GCC, then you would want to use its `-fopenmp` option for both compilation and linking.